# How can we pass List and variable through named route in Getx Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I pass data in getx routes but I don't understand how to get data on the next page.

```
List<UserModel> list = [];

var itemid = snapshot.data?.docs[index].id;


     Get.toNamed(RoutesName.editAddNewHome_Screen,
                                arguments: [List[index],itemid ]);
```

I tried to get data on the next page but it showed an error.

```
List<dynamic> args = Get.arguments;

 List<String> listData = args[0];
   var myVariable = args[1];
```

error - The instance member 'args' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: Can you post a MRE of the next page?

Comment: so which one is good for state management?

Answer (score 1):

With Getx Routing data are passed as map to an arguments

```
Get.toNamed(RoutesName.editAddNewHome_Screen,arguments: {"itemId: itemid ]);
```

In your case for retrieving the passed data using Get.arguments["itemId"],
You can retrieve this data directly on your Widget, or get the value on initState this will solve **error** - The instance member 'args' can't be accessed in an initializer.

```
String itemId = “”;

@override
void initState() {
  itemId= Get.arguments[“itemId”]??"”
  super.initState();
}
```

But I would suggest making this data required on the screen and then passing this data on your route file

In your route file:

```
 GetPage(name: RoutesName.editAddNewHome_Screen, page: () => EditAddNewHome_Screen(itemId: Get.arguments["itemId"] as String), ),
```

For in-depth understanding, check: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md

Comment: Okay, thanks, it works, i pass arguments as a Map and receive data  

final itemId =  Get.arguments["id"] ;